# Concat Column2 data in one record based on column1 through JCL

Tags: dfsort

I have a file having parent and child data in column1 and column2 respectively.
I have a requirement to concat all the child from same parent in one record.
How can we achive this through JCL ?

Expected Result shoold be like this :
Input file :

```
Parent    |Child  
ABCDEFAAAA|1233444111  
ABCWEEAAAA|3456544111  
ABCDEFAAAA|3435677111  
HFFDDDAAAA|6444554111  
ABCDEFAAAA|2424234111  
HFFDDDAAAA|4334456111
```

Output should be like this

```
Parent    |Child  
ABCDEFAAAA|1233444111,3435677111,2424234111  
ABCWEEAAAA|3456544111  
HFFDDDAAAA|6444554111,4334456111
```

Comment: You cannot do this with `JCL`. `JCL` is the language to describe what a batch job shall do, i.e. what program to run with what input and output files. In you case, you want to run DFSort, so you need to study DFSort's commands, e.g JOIN, JOINKEY, etc. Try yourself, and then ask if you encounter errors you can't resolve yourself.

Comment: I think you'd have to form groups and number the members of each group. There use that number to do conditional overlays into different parts of the output record.

Is there a limit to the number of records in each group?

Comment: @MartinPacker Yes, there is a limit of 8 child for each parent. One Parent can have max 8 child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin packer pointed out, it can be done in a single pass of data and get the desired results. Here is a sample which can handle upto 99 children per parent, but only the first 10 are handled as OP mentioned that the max is only 8.

```
//STEP0100 EXEC PGM=SORT                       
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                         
//SORTIN   DD *                                
ABCDEFAAAA|1233444111                          
ABCWEEAAAA|3456544111                          
ABCDEFAAAA|3435677111                          
HFFDDDAAAA|6444554111                          
ABCDEFAAAA|2424234111                          
HFFDDDAAAA|4334456111                          
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                         
//SYSIN    DD *                                
  SORT FIELDS=(01,10,CH,A),EQUALS              
                                               
  OUTREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                   
             KEYBEGIN=(001,10),                
                 PUSH=(081:ID=8,               
                       090:SEQ=2)),            
                                               
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                   
                BEGIN=(090,2,ZD,EQ,01),        
                 PUSH=(094:12,10)),            
                                               
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                   
                BEGIN=(090,2,ZD,EQ,02),        
                  END=(090,2,ZD,EQ,01),        
                 PUSH=(105:12,10)),            
                                               
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                   
                BEGIN=(090,2,ZD,EQ,03),        
                  END=(090,2,ZD,EQ,01),        
                 PUSH=(116:12,10)),            
                                               
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                   
                BEGIN=(090,2,ZD,EQ,04),        
                  END=(090,2,ZD,EQ,01),        
                 PUSH=(127:12,10)),            
                                               
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                   
                BEGIN=(090,2,ZD,EQ,05),        
                  END=(090,2,ZD,EQ,01),        
                 PUSH=(138:12,10)),            

         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                                         
                BEGIN=(090,2,ZD,EQ,06),                              
                  END=(090,2,ZD,EQ,01),                              
                 PUSH=(149:12,10)),                                  
                                                                     
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                                         
                BEGIN=(090,2,ZD,EQ,07),                              
                  END=(090,2,ZD,EQ,01),                              
                 PUSH=(160:12,10)),                                  
                                                                     
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                                         
                BEGIN=(090,2,ZD,EQ,08),                              
                  END=(090,2,ZD,EQ,01),                              
                 PUSH=(171:12,10)),                                  
                                                                     
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                                         
                BEGIN=(090,2,ZD,EQ,09),                              
                  END=(090,2,ZD,EQ,01),                              
                 PUSH=(182:12,10)),                                  
                                                                     
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,                                         
                BEGIN=(090,2,ZD,EQ,10),                              
                  END=(090,2,ZD,EQ,01),                              
                 PUSH=(193:12,10)),                                  
                                                                     
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(090,2,ZD,EQ,01),                              
              OVERLAY=(105:99X)),                                    
                                                                     
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,                                          
              OVERLAY=(094:94,110,SQZ=(SHIFT=LEFT,MID=C',')))        
                                                 
  OUTFIL REMOVECC,NODETAIL,                                          
  SECTIONS=(81,8,                                                    
  TRAILER3=(01,12,94,110))                                           
/*
```

The output of this is

```
ABCDEFAAAA|21233444111,3435677111,2424234111       
ABCWEEAAAA|33456544111                             
HFFDDDAAAA|46444554111,4334456111
```

Answer (score 0):

For the give input data, I've tried the following to achieve the expected results:

---

**Step 1:**
I have used `WHEN=GROUP` with `KEYBEGIN`, `PUSH` and `SEQ` parameters.

```
//Z02923A JOB 1,NOTIFY=&SYSUID                               
//STEP01  EXEC PGM=SORT                                      
//SORTIN  DD *                                               
ABCDEFAAAA|1233444111                                        
ABCWEEAAAA|3456544111                                        
ABCDEFAAAA|3435677111                                        
HFFDDDAAAA|6444554111                                        
ABCDEFAAAA|2424234111                                        
HFFDDDAAAA|4334456111                                        
//SORTOUT DD DSN=Z02923.SO.OUT1,                             
//        DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),                              
//        SPACE=(CYL,(2,0),RLSE),                            
//        DCB=(LRECL=80,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0)                  
//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                        
//SYSIN   DD *                                               
  OUTREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,KEYBEGIN=(1,11),PUSH=(50:SEQ=1)),
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(50,1,CH,EQ,C'1'),BUILD=(1,11,         
                       12:12,10,                                      
                       22:Z,                                          
                       21Z)),                                         
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(50,1,CH,EQ,C'2'),BUILD=(1,11,                  
                       12:11Z,                                        
                       23:12,10,                                      
                       33:11Z)),                                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(50,1,CH,EQ,C'3'),BUILD=(1,11,                  
                       12:22Z,                                        
                       12,10,                                         
                       Z))                                            
  SORT FIELDS=(1,11,CH,A)                                             
/*
```

`KEYBEGIN=(1,11)` means position 1 to 11 defines the key and any change in the value of the key implies the start of a new group. It is imperative to note that I'm including the 11th byte, which holds the pipe symbol, as part of the key.

`PUSH=(50:SEQ=1)` means position 50 contains a 1 byte sequence number for each record in a group. When the key value changes, the sequence number resets to 1.

### **Low value ain't an enemy all the time ;)**

I've used the sequence number, that we PUSHed, in the `IFTHEN` clauses to arrange the fields by inserting binary zeros (aka Low value i.e., X'00') in between as placeholders so that I can coalesce similar group records into one. I've covered that in the later sections of this answer.

Please note that I intend to add a space between the Child fields. This becomes handy when I squeeze the output in the final step with a comma in between the fields separated by spaces.

Let's take a look at the output dataset created out of the first step.

```
***************************** Top of Data ******************************
ABCDEFAAAA|1233444111                                                   
ABCDEFAAAA|           2424234111                                        
ABCDEFAAAA|                      3435677111                             
ABCWEEAAAA|3456544111                                                   
HFFDDDAAAA|4334456111                                                   
HFFDDDAAAA|           6444554111                                        
**************************** Bottom of Data ****************************
```

With Hex mode ON, you will be able to see the binary zeros (X'00).

```
***************************** Top of Data ******************************
ABCDEFAAAA|1233444111                                                   
CCCCCCCCCC4FFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000044444444444444444444444444444
1234561111F1233444111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ABCDEFAAAA|           2424234111                                        
CCCCCCCCCC400000000000FFFFFFFFFF0000000000044444444444444444444444444444
1234561111F0000000000024242341110000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ABCDEFAAAA|                      3435677111                             
CCCCCCCCCC40000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFF04444444444444444444444444444
1234561111F0000000000000000000000343567711100000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ABCWEEAAAA|3456544111                                                   
CCCECCCCCC4FFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000044444444444444444444444444444
1236551111F3456544111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
HFFDDDAAAA|4334456111                                                   
CCCCCCCCCC4FFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000044444444444444444444444444444
8664441111F4334456111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
HFFDDDAAAA|           6444554111                                        
CCCCCCCCCC400000000000FFFFFFFFFF0000000000044444444444444444444444444444
8664441111F0000000000064445541110000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
**************************** Bottom of Data ****************************
```

---

**Step 2:** The output dataset from Step 1 is passed as input to Step 2.

```
//STEP02  EXEC PGM=SORT,COND=(0,NE)              
//SORTIN  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=Z02923.SO.OUT1         
//SORTOUT DD DSN=Z02923.SO.OUT2,                 
//        DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),                  
//        SPACE=(CYL,(2,0),RLSE),                
//        DCB=(LRECL=80,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0)      
//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                            
//SYSIN   DD *                                   
  SORT FIELDS=(1,11,CH,A)                        
  SUM FIELDS=(12,8,20,8,28,8,36,8),FORMAT=BI     
  ALTSEQ CODE=(0040)                             
  OUTREC FIELDS=(1,80,TRAN=ALTSEQ)               
/*
```

As the input is sorted on the first 11 bytes, I've used `SUM FIELDS` to combine each records of a group into one.
Binary addition takes place with `SUM FIELDS=(12,8,20,8,28,8,36,8),FORMAT=BI` statement.

### **What really happens with the `SUM FIELDS` and Binary zeros?**

Binary addition operates on two bit patterns. Let's consider the following records (Hex mode is ON as I would like to show how Binary addition is being performed on the Hex values).

```
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7--
***************************** Top of Data ******************************
ABCDEFAAAA|1233444111                                                   
CCCCCCCCCC4FFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000044444444444444444444444444444
1234561111F1233444111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ABCDEFAAAA|           2424234111                                        
CCCCCCCCCC400000000000FFFFFFFFFF0000000000044444444444444444444444444444
1234561111F0000000000024242341110000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hex value of the 12th byte in 1st record, X'F1' is being added with the binary zeros in the 12th byte in 2nd record as the keys are same.

```
 F1
+00
 --
 F1
```

X'F1' denotes number '1' in EBCDIC

If we change the Binary zero in the 12th byte of 2nd record to Binary one (X'01'), results will vary.

```
 F1
+01
 --
 F2
```

X'F2' denotes number '2' in EBCDIC.

With Binary zeros we can perform SUM FIELDS on Alphanumeric data items (EBCDIC characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9) to group them onto one single record.

ALTSEQ CODE=(0040) is used to convert the unused Binary Zeros (X'00) to spaces (X'40').

The output from Step 2 is shown below:

```
***************************** Top of Data ******************************
ABCDEFAAAA|1233444111 2424234111 3435677111                             
ABCWEEAAAA|3456544111                                                   
HFFDDDAAAA|4334456111 6444554111                                        
**************************** Bottom of Data ****************************
```

---

**Step 3:** In this step, I'm left squeezing the output from Step 2 with `MID=C','` to  to create comma separated fields.

```
//STEP03  EXEC PGM=SORT,COND=(0,NE)             
//SORTIN  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=Z02923.SO.OUT2        
//SORTOUT DD DSN=Z02923.SO.OUT3,                
//        DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),                 
//        SPACE=(CYL,(2,0),RLSE),               
//        DCB=(LRECL=80,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0)     
//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                           
//SYSIN   DD *                                  
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                              
  OUTREC FIELDS=(1,80,SQZ=(SHIFT=LEFT,MID=C','))
/*
```

Output from Step 3

```
***************************** Top of Data ******************************
ABCDEFAAAA|1233444111,2424234111,3435677111                             
ABCWEEAAAA|3456544111                                                   
HFFDDDAAAA|4334456111,6444554111                                        
**************************** Bottom of Data ****************************
```

---

and there you go!
You can definitely scale up this solution to accommodate the max limit of 8 child fields.

Hope this helps!